# OS X - Adopt "command not found" behavior from Ubuntu

Tags: macos, bash, shell, .bash-profile

There is a question about overriding the default *command not found* behavior on Ubuntu. It is [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73262/how-do-i-teach-bash-in-ubuntu-some-curse-words). I tried adding the following to ~/.bash_profile, /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile, but no luck:

```
function command_not_found_handle {
  echo "oops!"
}
```

How can I do the exact same thing in OS X?

Comment: Try adding it to either `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not some feature of bash or OS X as clearly implied in the referenced article. As evidence, you also have ["I deleted my /etc/bash.bashrc"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55552/i-accidentally-overwrite-etc-bash-bashrc-file-please-give-the-default-content). In other words, nothing is calling the handle on your system and hence no effect.

You need to get the source of that package and compile (or even port, but there may be equivalents) it on OS X. Then you would add the ***if*** (below) to the *default bash profile on OS X*, which should be somewhere in /etc.

**Part of /etc/bash.bashrc from Ubuntu**

```
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/bin/python /usr/share/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
        else
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Comment: The "package" may be a bash hack or patch and not some kernel-level extension as I thought when writing the answer. If that is the case, your chances of replicating the desired effect are much greater.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it *is* a feature of bash, but only in newer versions:

> There is a new builtin error-handling function named command_not_found_handle.

from https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html

You likely need to `brew install bash` to get the latest version.  From there it works just like you'd hope:

```
$ function command_not_found_handle {
> echo "w00t - '$@' command not found"
> }
$ lkjsdf
w00t - 'lkjsdf' command not found
```

Note that you'll also likely need to change your shell.  The instructions for that seem to be terminal specific (Terminal vs. iTerm, etc.) so make sure to google that too.